# How do you gain titles like Grisly Pointman?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the extra words next to players name and level mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85313/what-do-the-extra-words-next-to-players-name-and-level-mean)

I have a level 25 Commando who has the title Pointman. I was playing in a multiplayer game yesterday and noticed a level 24 Commando who had the title Grisly Pointman. I don't remember ever having this title at level 24. In fact, I think I have been a Pointman ever since I started.

I tried changing my skill point distribution (twice) - no effect on title.

I also have a badass rank of more than 3200, which I believe is fairly high for my level. Would this have an effect on my title?

So I'd like to know: 1) How do I get a different title? 2) If possible, does someone have a list of all the titles available?

Comment: @bwarner - Oh, good catch. I may have to move my answer over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is taken from the classmod you have equipped. There are over 100 different titles possible, so instead of writing out the whole list here, I will link to the lists of class mods on the Borderlands 2 wiki.

[Commando](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Commando/Mods)

[Siren](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Siren/Mods)

[Gunzerker](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Gunzerker/Mods)

[Assassin](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Assassin/Mods)

Under *Possible Skill Boost* on that page, the word in parentheses goes before the name of the classmod, so the title of a Commando with the first mod and variant on the list would be **Front Line Engineer**.

Comment: That would've been the last thing I checked... Do you happen to have a list.. at least for Commando? I can't imagine this being too long a list.

Comment: Well, there are 27 titles per class. I'll link to the wiki pages which list class mods.

Answer (score 0):

The full list of titles and prefixes are given at the following link:

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Class_Mod#Axton

> These prefixes will note the skills given by the class mod, with the prefix determining the highest skill bonus of each mod.