# How do you obtain the grisly pointman title in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I have had the POINTMAN class mod for about 10 levels and i wanted to change it to GRISLY POINTMAN but i don't know how. I have heard that you must add skill bonuses that come with POINTMAN to last ditch effort but i do not have that option. Could someone please tell me EXACTLY how to obtain the GRISLY POINTMAN title.
The exact specifications of my class mod is: *Level requirement 12, Health Regeneration +2.6, Max Health +69* THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This has already been covered in a couple of other questions previously, [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85313/what-do-the-extra-words-next-to-players-name-and-level-mean) and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89426/how-do-you-gain-titles-like-grisly-pointman).

However, specific to your question you will want the POINTMAN class mod (which you already have) and the tier two ability [Last Ditch Effort](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Ditch_Effort) as per [this article](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Class_Mod#Axton) on the Borderlands 2 Wikia pages.

The [linked article from Wikia](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Class_Mod#Axton) contains information on which class mod and skill combinations need to be used in order to get each of the titles in the game.